# generics unchecked warning conversion

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have read in generics that "? extends Object" and "?" are synonymous then why this occurs.

```
List list=new ArrayList();
List<? extends Object> list2=list;     //1
List<?> list3=list;                    //2
```

For 1 unchecked conversion warning is thrown but not for 2. So the compiler somewhere is definitely differentiating between the two. 
Plz explain the difference between the two with respect to the above code

Comment: Both is working on IntelliJ identically.

Comment: @Smutje what does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

> I have read in generics that "? extends Object" and "?" are synonymous

Not quite. The first wildcard has a lower bound, the second does not. For your two examples it should not make a difference (well, except that you can only add `null` to `list2` and `list3`!).

This lower bound *can* make a difference: "erasure signature" (I don't know the exact term).

The best example for this is [`Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-); you will notice that the parameter type is defined as `T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>`.

This is because prior to Java 5 this method existed and was defined as:

```
static Object max(Collection coll)
```

If the type parameter were defined as `T extends Comparable<? super T>`, this would have meant that the method in 1.4 would have had to return a `Comparable`!

Answer (score 0):

Because some type information is erased during compilation, not all types are available at run time. Types that are completely available at run time are known as **reifiable types**(see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7).

So according to JLS `List<?>` is a reifiable type, but `List<? extends Object>` is not, which means they are not the same from compiler point of view.